# UWP How to add audio to video?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, video-encoding

I am working on Universal Windows Application.I need add audio(.aac or .mp3) to video background(.mp4).

I used `MediaComposition` that while rendering dropped resolution and file size.
Example My MP4 Video is 22.5 MB and Audio is 2.5 mb after render`MediaComposition` dropped resolution and new file is just 8.5MB i tried `MediaEncodingProfile` `HD720p` but rendered file 178.5MB. I need just add audio to video background.

I am using this

```
        StorageFile fileTarget = await folder.CreateFileAsync(name, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        try
        {
            MediaComposition composition = new MediaComposition();
            composition.Clips.Add(await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile));
            BackgroundAudioTrack backgroundTrack = await BackgroundAudioTrack.CreateFromFileAsync(audioFile);
            composition.BackgroundAudioTracks.Add(backgroundTrack);
            var progress = new Progress<double>(percent =>
            {
                vPercent.Text = $"{(int)percent}%{Environment.NewLine}";
            });
            //await composition.RenderToFileAsync(fileTarget,MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise,MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.HD720p)).AsTask(progress);
            //await composition.RenderToFileAsync(fileTarget,MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise).AsTask(progress);
            await composition.RenderToFileAsync(fileTarget).AsTask(progress);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log($"An error had been throwed, {ex.Message}");
            await fileTarget.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
        }
```

Comment: Essentially you want to remux the video file - MP4 isn't best suited to that. MKV as a container file would make that easier, but either way there are no native .Net or UWP API's for muxing files, it'd have to be a third party library.

Comment: I found FFmpeg third party library but it dont render file on uwp :( @JohnnyWestlake

Comment: Contributing to the file size, in order of importance, are the parameters that set the video bit rate, audio sample frequency, audio bit rate, then frame size. So, you need to compare these parameters with the original source file.

Comment: i tried this await MediaEncodingProfile.CreateFromFileAsync(videofile) ut same result. @XavierXie-MSFT